# Is there a better way to rewrite this NumPy Snippet

Tags: python, numpy, refactoring

I have the following Python (NumPy) and I want to refactor it be cleaner (and possibly faster):

```
temp = max(value for (x, y), value in np.ndenumerate(cm) if x * y < 100 and (x, y) != (0, 0) and not np.isnan(value))
```

I think it is pretty clear what I want to do. All in all, I try to filter some elements of a 2D array based on some conditions on it's values and indices.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output as well.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think it's the shortest way because of `x*y<100` comparison

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand, randint 

cm = rand(50, 100)
cm[randint(0, 50, 4000), randint(0, 100, 4000)] = np.nan

temp1 = max(value for (x, y), value in np.ndenumerate(cm) if x * y < 100 and (x, y) != (0, 0) and not np.isnan(value))

x, y = np.indices(cm.shape)
mask = (x * y < 100) & (x + y != 0) & (~np.isnan(cm))
temp2 = np.max(cm[mask])

assert temp1 == temp2
```

**Edit**

for `max(x+y * value)`:

```
np.max((x + y * cm)[mask])
```

or

```
np.max(x[mask] + y[mask] * cm[mask])
```

Comment: might be slightly faster to simply set `mask[0,0] = False` instead of checking if x + y != 0 for every cell.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But What if I need "value" to be a function of x,y and value; not just the value. For example if I would like to have the max(x+y * value)

Comment: @FlorentsTselai you should update your question to include sample input and expected output, or possibly ask a new question with these details. It's very hard for people to guess what your data looks like (shape, data type, etc) and what exactly you are after in terms of results if you don't provide this information.